# Meteor JS - can't get ReactiveVar from helper

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

Have problem with reading ReactiveVar in my login template. Source:

```
Template.login.onCreated(function() {
    this.loginError = new ReactiveVar();
});
Template.login.events({
    'submit #login_form': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
Template.login.onRendered(function() {
    const instance = this;
    this.$('#login_form').validate({
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorClass: 'input-field_error',
        rules: {
        email: {
            required: false,
            email: false
        },
        password: {
            required: false
        }
    },
    messages: {
        email: {
            required: "Не оставляйте это поле пустым.",
            email: "Проверьте корректность e-mail."
        },
        password: {
            required: "Не оставляйте это поле пустым."
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var email = $('#login-email').val(),
            password = $('#login-password').val();
        Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function(error) {
            if (error)
                instance.loginError.set(true);
        });
    }
    });
});
Template.login.helpers({
    loginError: function() {
        return Template.instance().loginError.get();
    }
});
```

I call out error in loginWithPassword. In my html template i have:

```
{{#if loginError}}
<script>
    Materialize.toast({{loginError}}, 3000);
</script>
{{/if}}
```

But it doesn't work. Template can see this var with manual set like a this.loginError.set(true) in onCreated function.
Need your help.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/gzjo6r this line work good

Comment: I doubt trying to insert a `<script>` tag dynamically in a Blaze template would have it executed, and in particular parse the Blaze placeholders. Why not just calling directly your `toast` in case of error?

Comment: @ghybs thanks for your answer! This works if I set ReactiveVar not in loginWithPassword callback function. I will change <script> for simple html-tags with errors. I need to understand why template doesn't see reactive changes in loginWithPassword callback function.

Comment: `{{#if loginError}}<div>Error!</div>{{/if}}` in this case doesn't work too.